# How to make a <td> cover the height of its content

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am practicing HTML emailing lately and I have come up with some trouble using tables. Right now, the content of a `<td>` is bigger than the `<td>` itself.

**So how do you make a `td` adjust its size according to its content?** I feel like the rest of the `td`'s on this email worked just fine. Notice that what is giving me trouble is an `<a>` to which I have given some padding to style as a button.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 45%;">
      <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="house1.jpg" width="300" height="200">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <h6 style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: 900; margin: 0; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Modern House of such style</h6>

            <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; margin: 0; padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam quis.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; display:inline-block; padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px; background-color: #f95965">CLICK HERE</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This last **`td`** is the one giving me some trouble. Any ideas?

Comment: The issue is not your `td`, it is that by default `a` elements are `inline` and so dont take on their padding properties the same way block elements do. Add `display:inline-block;` to your `a` element

Comment: Done, worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Display property for content like `display:block;` or `display:inline-block` check this example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
     <td style="width: 45%;">
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
 <tr>
   <td>
   <img src="house1.jpg" width="300" height="200">
   </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
    <td align="center">
    <h6 style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: 900; margin: 0; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Modern House of such style</h6>
           <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; margin: 0; padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam quis.</p>
 </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td align="center">
   <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px; background-color: #f95965;display: inline-block;">CLICK HERE</a>
   </td>
 </tr>
                    
</body>
</html>
```